# How to find adjacent points in a 3D space in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, adjacency-list

I have a couple of points in a 3D space, and I want to write a condition to determine whether two points are adjacent: are they only a single unit apart in the integer lattice?

I have a struct named Point that holds x,y and z coordinates. Then in the main function, I set the values for points a,b,c,d,e and push them into a vector. Then in the for loop I want to check if two points are adjacent or not. Currently I'm just checking if they are on the same axis, but I do not know how to proceed.

```
struct Point {
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
};
bool adjacent(Point a, Point b) { ??? }

int main() {
    struct Point a = {0, 0, 0};
    struct Point b = {0, 0, -1};
    struct Point c = {1, 0, -1};
    struct Point d = {1, -1, -1};
    struct Point e = {2, -1, -1};

    assert(adjacent(a, b));
    assert(adjacent(b, c));
    assert(adjacent(c, d));
    assert(adjacent(d, e));
    assert(!adjacent(a, c));
}
```

By adjacent I mean something like in this photo:
[image]

Comment: We need you to define "adjacent" for this application.

Comment: @Prune I added a picture where "points" are connected and the adjacent ones are conected directly to each other

Comment: I think I understand: you need the coordinates to differ by exactly 1 on a single axis.  Can you code that logic?

Comment: @Prune that is exactly right. And I don't know how to tackle this kind of problem. Coding is not the problem I need to understand the logic. Once I have that then it's all good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very briefly:

```
for each pair of points:
    if two of the three coordinates are equal AND
              the other coordinate differs by 1:
        then mark the pair as adjacent.
```

Iterating through point pairs is simple enough: the first point `a` walks through indices 0-(n-2); the second point `b` walks through indices from `a`'s position through the end, `n-1`.

Checking adjacency is also easy, given integer coordinates.

```
diff = abs(a.x - b.x) + 
       abs(a.y - b.y) + 
       abs(a.z - b.z)
```

`diff` = 1 **iff** the points are adjacent.

Comment: Just to add - can reduce time complexity from O(N^2) to O(N log N) for a large number of points using a k-D tree.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: thanks!  I keep forgetting about these ... showing my age, I guess.